# Solve $x^{257} \equiv 5 \pmod {2016}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solve:
$$x^{257} \equiv 5 \pmod {2016}$$

I know you have to use the Euclidean algorithm but I'm not sure how.

I know the prime factorization of 2016 is $2^5 \times 3^2 \times7$.

Comment: Maybe useful: $\phi(2016) = 2016 \times \dfrac12 \times \dfrac23 \times \dfrac67 = 576$.

Comment: @KennyLau, It's easier to use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html  as $2016$ is composite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

As $(2^5,7)=(2^2,3^2)=(3^2,7)=1$

Let us $x^{257}\equiv5\pmod7$  etc.

As $\phi(7)=6,$ and $257\equiv-1\pmod6$

$$ 5\equiv x^{257}\equiv x^{-1}\pmod7\iff x\equiv5^{-1}\equiv3\pmod7\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Similarly, $\phi(3^2)=6\implies 5\equiv\cdots x^{-1}\pmod{3^2}\iff x\equiv2\pmod{3^2}\ \ \ \  (2)$

and by [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) $$\lambda(2^5)=2^3$$ and $257\equiv1\pmod{2^3}\implies$  $$x\equiv5^1\pmod{2^5}\ \ \ \  (3)$$

Now apply Chinese Remainder Theorem on $(1),(2),(3)$

Comment: If you're dealing with primes, you don't need Euler. You just need Fermat.

Comment: @KennyLau,  Are $3^2,2^5$ primes?

Comment: No, but $7$ is.

Comment: @KennyLau, True.There we could avoid Euler Totient Theorem

Comment: Also, in your first line: primes must be co-prime...

Comment: @KennyLau, Do you find anything wrong there? I mentioned  it as demanded by http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: I think the problem is a fairly routine application of offshoot of eulers theorem, completely independent of C.R.T. Namely that $$x=y\ mod \  \phi(n)$$ and $$a^x=a^y \ mod \ n$$.

Comment: @marshalcraft, Have u found anything wrong in the post?

Comment: I don't know that it solves the question, frankly it's unclear. But for sake that it does if you make any edit I will remove vote.

Comment: @marshalcraft, You don't have to remove vote. Just check if the update makes thing clear for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use eulers theorem. Or a coralary of it.

$$x=y \ mod \ \phi(n)$$ and $$ a^x=a^y \ mod \ n$$

To raise both sides to the appropriate power to get just $x$ on left and $5$ to some large power $mod \ 2016$.

So $\phi(2^5)\phi(3^2)\phi(7)=(16)(6)(6)=576$

So we need $257\cdot a = 1 \ mod \ 576$, solving gets $a=65$.

So $(x^{257})^{65}=x=5^{65}=101 \ mod \  2016$.

Key here is Euler's Theorem.

Comment: As $2016$ is composite we  can use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html  $$\lambda(2016 )=24$$   and $$1\equiv257a\equiv17a\pmod{24}\implies a\equiv17$$  as $$17^2\equiv1\pmod{24}$$