# Solve $x^{247} \equiv y \pmod {2016}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I asked a question like this earlier but I'm looking for a more general answer.

Solve:
$$x^{247} \equiv y \pmod {2016}$$

I know you have to use the Euclidean algorithm but I'm not sure how.

I know the prime factorization of 2016 is $2^5 \times 3^2 \times7$.

Additionally, I know that $\phi (2016)$=576.

Comment: For the case $\gcd(y,2016)=1$  we have $\gcd(x,2016)=1,$  so $\gcd(x,2^5(=\gcd (x,3^2)=\gcd(x,7)=1.$...... (1). Modulo $2^5$, we have  $x^8\equiv 1$ so $x^{247}\equiv y  \iff x^7\equiv y\iff 1\equiv x^8\equiv xy.$ ..... (2). Modulo $3^2$  we have  $x^6\equiv 1$ so $x^{247}\equiv y\iff x\equiv y.$ .... (3). Modulo $7$ we have $x^6\equiv 1$ so $x^{247}\equiv y\iff x\equiv y$... The method of proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem provides an algorithm for finding all $x$  that satisfy these three conditions.

Comment: we can use mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html
$$\lambda(2016)=24$$ See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281562/solve-x257-equiv-5-pmod-2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some introduction :

Tonelli-shanks algorithm can solve this problem $x^2 = b \mod p$ for $p$ prime number, also can be generalized for $n$ composite.

For the general case $x^a = b \mod p$  its easy solve-able if $gcd(a,p-1)=1$ and $(b,p)=1$ and it becomes very complicated when the condition fails (yet there are many papers dealing with this situation on arXiv), and this can be generalized to $n$ composite by using $\phi(n)$ where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler function.

In your case $gcd(247,\phi(2016)=576)=1$, so its easily solve-able if $gcd(y,2016)=1$ which means that $2\not| y$ and $3\not|y$ and $7\not|y$.

Its simply by this equation $x=y^{7} \mod 2016$, the reason for this is that $247^{-1} = 7 \mod \phi(2016)=576$.(Read about why this works given the above conditions in the internet).

For Example : $x^{247} = 131\mod 2016$ and since $gcd(131,2016)=1$, the solution is $x = 131^{7} = 1643 \mod 2016$ so $x=1643$.

**Note** there is more than one solution $-x \mod 2016$ is also a solution and there might be more solutions.

Comment: That's incorrect. $1643^{247} mod 2016 \equiv 131$ not $5$

Comment: @shrindle $5^{7} \mod 2016 = 1517 \not= 1643$, so were is the problem ?